# Can ReSharper's test runner be configure not to show Debug.WriteLine() messages?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics, resharper-6.0

I want to omit Debug.Write/WriteLine messages from ReSharper's test runner output. Is it doable?

Comment: `while (Debug.Listeners.Count != 0) Debug.Listeners.RemoveAt(0);` :)

Comment: my original question contained the answer that I thought didn't work. But it did, I just was running it at a wrong time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (Debug.Listeners.Count > 0) Debug.Listeners.RemoveAt(0);
```

or more targeted (for NUnit test framework):

```
var nunitListener = Debug.Listeners.Cast<TraceListener>().Where(tl => tl.Name == "NUnit").FirstOrDefault();
if (nunitListener != null) Debug.Listeners.Remove(nunitListener);
```

Notice that though ReSharper adds its own trace listener, it is NUnit's trace listener that Test Runner shows in the output. I do not know why, but removing "NUnit" trace listener does the trick.